# how to apply multiple css image filters using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I apply the following css code using jquery

```
#centeredImage
{
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%) invert(0) blur(1px); 
}
```

Already tried this, didn't work

```
$('#centeredImage').css('-webkit-filter','grayscale(20%) invert(0) blur(1px)');
```

Comment: It works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/fn55v/

Comment: try `...css('WebkitFilter', ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WebkitFilter` instead:

```
$("#centeredImage").css({
    WebkitFilter: 'grayscale(20%) invert(0) blur(1px)'
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eA7Bv/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

Just use filter:

```
$('#centeredImage').css('filter','grayscale(20%) invert(0) blur(1px)');
```

jQuery automatically set prefixes.

Comment: the normal filter tag doesn't work for me at all, not even using css only.
I'm using the newest chrome version on fedora..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create css as a class

```
.centered-image
{
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%) invert(0) blur(1px); 
}
```

Then in jQuery

```
$('#centeredImage').addClass('centered-image');
```

At least this way your keeping the separation of javascript and styling...